# Multiple LEMP/Wordpress Websites: one server for each site or all of them in one server?

Tags: nginx, wordpress

My company develops and maintains Wordpress websites for small non-profits. Currently, we develop and maintain around 20 sites, all of them with low traffic.

All sites are hosted in one VPS, using LEMP stack, fastcache and redis.

I see several benefits of holding all sites in one VPS, but also some problems, specially related to security and performance.

My question is: generally speaking, what are the pros and cons of hosting several low traffic Wordpress websites in one VPS in relation to picking one VPS for each site?

Wordpress multisite is not in question.

Comment: Please see https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning

Comment: Benchmark your sites, see how many you can place on a single host.

Comment: My questions is not about capacity planning; I'm not asking how much RAM or processors do I need. Rather, I want to discuss philosophical aspects of both approaches.

Comment: You are asking how many sites you can run on a single instance. That's capacity planning. Philosophical discussions have no place here.

Comment: Please point me where I asked how many sites I can run in a single instance. My question is conceptual, about pros and cons of both approaches.